# Overriding login view to redirect user to different page according to their permission

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to redirect logged in user to different form according to their permission.

So say if user is superuser or admin then he will be redirected to default django admin dash board.
And if user is not a superuser then he will be redirected to different custom dashboard page.

So what is a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you are using class based views, override the get method, check if the user is a superuser and accordingly redirect. You can either implement this as a mixin or override the method directly in your class.
RedirectView would be the Class you are looking for:
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.base/RedirectView/

Comment: @petkostas I am not using it yet. But i think what you want to say is Extending AuthenticationForm then overriding its get method and then using its instance with custom user admin..!! OR How it will works with admin login page..Can you provide a example..

Comment: You don't provide much detail, but if you are implementing a custom dashboard for simple users, then a check for is_superuser in your view, if it's true then the user is an admin and you can redirect him to the admin dashboard, if the user is a simple user just provide him with the rest of the flow.

Comment: @petkostas Actually i just started developing this project. Sorry that i didnt mentioned it. Actually what i am asking is that i am using django admin login screen, so where should i put that test(is superuser or not) and redirect the request. I must have to override some views which is used by django admin on login screen. so which view is it. And if using class based view than how to integrate it with Django admin.